# MSCRM Dll ILMerge

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, ilmerge

can i merge(ILMerge) .net framework version 4.0 dll with 3.5.

I need a merged version dll in 3.5 as my mscrm 4.0 plugin will only supports 3.5 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 4.0 and .NET 3.5 run on different versions of the CLR.  3.5 is built on top of the 2.0 CLR and .NET 4.0 runs on the 4.0 CLR.  Because of this you will be unable to merge the two.  CRM 2011 supports .NET 4.0 code when using the CRM 2011 SDK and .NET 3.5 code when using the CRM 4 SDK (for backwards compatibility).  I would recommend converting your code to .NET 4.0 if you are working with CRM 2011 and sticking with .NET 3.5 if you are writing code for CRM 4.

Perhaps if you gave more information on why you are trying to do this, I could provide a better answer.